# Re-using Alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, alias

I want to ask something about reusing alias.

I have some example like this,

1st query:

```
select
@tmp1 := if(AA.id= '','abcde','yuiop') as tmp1,
CONCAT_WS('-',
SUBSTR(@tmp1, 1, 2),
SUBSTR(@tmp1, 3, 4),
SUBSTR(@tmp1, 5)
) AS tmp1_res
FROM some_database as AA
```

2nd query:

```
select
CONCAT_WS('-',
SUBSTR(if(AA.id= '','abcde','yuiop'), 1, 2),
SUBSTR(if(AA.id= '','abcde','yuiop'), 3, 4),
SUBSTR(if(AA.id= '','abcde','yuiop'), 5)
) AS tmp1_res
FROM some_database as AA
```

Both query runs well but I wonder which one is more efficient.

In the 1st query, I see that substring only calls a specific, in my opinion, 'placeholder' variable. I assume it won't check AA.id 3 times first, then split them up, which I guess it will be more efficient. Is this correct ?

Thank you

EDIT

thank you for the replies. I just tested both methods, turns out that the 2nd method is a bit faster (about 0.001~0.004 seconds) than the 1st one.

another thing I don't really understand, as for the 1st query, is the behavior same as the 2nd query or not ? (as far as I understand, the 2nd query check the id column by if-condition each time substract function is being used, meanwhile 1st one only doing if-condition once)

Comment: Looking at the execution plan would tell you if there is a significant difference between them.

Comment: SQL Queries do not get executed in exactly the same way as you write them. Query optimizers treat common elements of a query as units, and then re-use those units as it sees fit. You may find that the explain (execution) plan is exactly the same. You aren't dealing with column aliases here by the way, but with using variables instead of if functions.

Comment: I doubt you notice a different unless you execute it a billion times. Go for whatever you think of is most readable. The first is easier to make changes in just one place, the second is simpler. Up to you.